# Motion layout stops working after adding click listener to any view

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-motionlayout

So here's the situation. I have motion layout setup with multiple OnSwipe and OnClick  that all work together and create a smooth animation. However when I add a click listener to any child of the motion layout like this simple one:

```
darkenForeground.setOnClickListener {
            Log.e("HI","");
        }
```

all motion layout functionality stops working and isn't responding to any swipes or clicks. And the new added click listener isn't even called. If you have any ideas why this could be happening let me know. Any help is welcome. Thanks!

Here is full layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+id/mainMotion"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="234dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="HELLO"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>



    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/darkenForeground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0.0"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>

    <com.lijiankun24.shadowlayout.ShadowLayout
        android:id="@+id/topContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:shadowColor="#66000000"
        app:shadowDy="2dp"
        app:shadowRadius="4dp"
        app:shadowShape="rectangle"
        app:shadowSide="bottom">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/top_gradient"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </com.lijiankun24.shadowlayout.ShadowLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/draggable"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/drag_shape"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/topContainer"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />





</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

Full scene

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="1000">
       <KeyFrameSet>
       </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/topContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    </ConstraintSet>
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/expanded_top" >
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/topContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="450dp"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/darkenForeground"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alpha="0.5" />
    </ConstraintSet>
    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/expanded_top"
        motion:duration="300">
        <OnSwipe motion:dragDirection="dragDown"
            motion:touchRegionId="@id/topContainer"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@id/draggable" />
        <OnClick />
    </Transition>
</MotionScene>
```

Full activity

```
package com.gooofystudios.calc

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.DisplayMetrics
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.security.AccessController.getContext


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        initViews()

    }

    private fun initViews(){
        /*darkenForeground.setOnClickListener {
            Log.e("HI","");
        }*/
       ///Uncommenting this will cause motion layout to stop working

    }


    ///Ignore this (is not even called)
    fun Int.toPx(): Int{
        val displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics = resources.displayMetrics
        return Math.round(this * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT))
    }
}
```

Comment: You have transition added for this Event this is why its gets override .. If you want to do Some stuff after Motion ends or in between you can use a Motion listener ..

Answer (score 0):

Add the clicklistener from XML ..ie

```
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/darkenForeground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.0"
    android:onClick="doSomething"
    android:background="@android:color/black"/>
```